# C# 3.5 Merge 2 lists of 2 different types

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have 2 generic Lists  `List<type1> L1` ,  `List<type2> L2` in C# 3.5

**Problem:** type1 has an attribute called "key1" and type2 has an attribute called "key2"
How to merge L1 and L2 on key1 = key2.
Both lists are unsorted  but I'm welcome to any ideas on how to sort the lists based on the attribute.

I'd like to be able to merge the two lists on a key. I know it's not a dictionary and it would've been nice if it was but there is a very specific reason why they are lists which I will not get in to because that is irrelevant.

Comment: What type would the resultant list be?

Comment: Do you mean attribute as in an `Attribute` or merely as a property?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the result ought to be.  You want a list containing items in both that have matching keys or you want a list containing items from both but when the keys match you want to omit the subsequent elements with that key or somehow combine them?

Comment: yeah, what do you mean by merge?  what are you expecting to come out of this with?  you can't have a List<> with multiple types.  I guess you could make it a List<object> or List<SOME_COMMON_BASECLASS>

Comment: I think it's a Join between the two lists, rather than merging the two lists into one.  "How to merge L1 and L2 __on key1 = key2__."

Comment: @Greg: Good point, I actually don't know, as long as I get 1 list is what's important. Perhaps I should make an interface?
@Anthony: sorry it's a property.

Comment: @Ehsan, but the other question remains: Are you looking for a L1 and L2 to be unioned/concatenated or are you wanting related items from L1 to be matched to items from L2? (as in, is the L1.Key==L2.Key relevant for eliminating duplicates or for pairing up items)

Comment: I want the latter, L1.Key == L2.Key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're asking for the Join operation. It's straightforward, but you are going to need to be more specific to get better answers.

```
var joined = from item1 in L1
             join item2 in L2
             on item1.Key1 equals item2.Key2
             orderby item1.Key1
             select new 
             {
                 // your selected objects/properties here
             };
```

Comment: is this not LINQ? I'm using C# 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
list1.Cast<object>().Union(list2.Cast<object>()).OrderBy(elem => elem is elem1 ? ((elem1)elem).key : ((elem2)elem).key)
```