# Use linq Intersects with a custom matching selector function

Tags: c#

I have a list of Person and a list of BirthDates and I would like to intersect person.BirthYear with BirthDates.Year

Intersects seems to need both lists to be of same type so my question is how to have a func or so which will allow to me write my own custom matching logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which doesn't needs both sequences to be of same type.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4521196/2530848) should help you with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code snippet for your case:
    using System;
    using System.Linq;

```
namespace Intersects
{
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var persons = new[]
                {
                    new Person() {Name = "Jack", BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1)},
                    new Person() {Name = "Joe", BirthDate = new DateTime(1970, 9, 9)},
                    new Person() {Name = "Ivan", BirthDate = new DateTime(1991, 2, 2)},
                };

            var birthDates = new[]
                {
                    new DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
                    new DateTime(1991, 2, 2),
                    new DateTime(1991, 3, 3),
                };

            var joined = from p in persons
                         join bd in birthDates
                         on p.BirthDate.Year equals bd.Year // Your own custom logic
                         select p;

            foreach (var person in joined)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
            }

            // Output:
            //Jack
            //Ivan
            //Ivan
        }
    }
}
```